# when use apache thrift in codeigniter show me class not found

Tags: php, codeigniter, thrift

I want to use apache thrift in codeigniter libaries.
I have the following codes. I have checked the files and they exist.
php version is `PHP 5.6.31`
thrift verion is `0.10.*`

```
use Thrift\Transport\TSocket;
use Thrift\Transport\TBufferedTransport;
use Thrift\Transport\THttpClient;
use Thrift\Protocol\TBinaryProtocol;
use Thrift\Exception\TException;
use Thrift\ClassLoader\ThriftClassLoader;
use \test\MyServiceClient;

class Cds2thriftclass extends Rootclass {
    private $_thrift_uri = "";
    private $_thrift_port = "";
    private $_timeout = 5000;

    private $transport;
    private $protocol;
    private $client;

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->_thrift_uri = 127.0.0.1;
        $this->_thrift_port = 8899;

        $THRIFT_ROOT = APPPATH . 'libraries/thrift10';
        require_once $THRIFT_ROOT.'/Thrift/ClassLoader/ThriftClassLoader.php';

        $GEN_DIR = $THRIFT_ROOT . '/Thrift/packages';

        $loader = new ThriftClassLoader();
        $loader->registerNamespace('Thrift', $THRIFT_ROOT);
        $loader->registerDefinition('test', $GEN_DIR);
        $loader->register();

        $this->transport = new TSocket($this->_thrift_uri, $this->_thrift_port);
        $this->transport->setRecvTimeout($this->_timeout);
        $this->transport = new TBufferedTransport($this->transport, 1024, 512);
        $this->protocol = new TBinaryProtocol($this->transport);
        $this->client = new \test\MyServiceClient($this->protocol);
```

then it show me the error:

```
Class 'test\MyServiceClient' not found in /apps/blog/application/libraries/mythriftclass.php
```

and I search this problem in google and ST, just this  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37383646/apache-thrift-not-loading-php-definition)  this about , but it not solve my problem.

Please let me know what I did wrong.

Thanks.

---

Now the problem is solved, just use php `require` func to load the file.
But anyhow thanks long's help.
The code is blow:

```
    $THRIFT_ROOT = APPPATH . 'libraries/thrift10';
    require_once $THRIFT_ROOT.'/Thrift/ClassLoader/ThriftClassLoader.php';

    $GEN_DIR = $THRIFT_ROOT . '/Thrift/packages';

    $loader = new ThriftClassLoader();
    $loader->registerNamespace('Thrift', $THRIFT_ROOT);
    $loader->registerDefinition('test', $GEN_DIR);
    $loader->register();

    $this->transport = new TSocket('127.0.0.1', 8899);
    $this->transport->setRecvTimeout($this->_timeout);
    $this->transport = new TBufferedTransport($this->transport, 1024, 512);
    $this->protocol = new TBinaryProtocol($this->transport);

    require_once $THRIFT_ROOT . '/Thrift/gen-php/test/Types.php';
    require_once $THRIFT_ROOT . '/Thrift/gen-php/test/Cds2APIService.php';

    $this->client = new MyServiceClient($this->protocol);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you use namespace ,you should use composer

you can `$config['composer_autoload'] = TRUE` in the `config/config.php` file; this option is modified to TRUE, and the default is FALSE

Attention here. If you modify the TRUE, then CI is automatically loaded `application/vendor/autoload.php` so, if your vendor directory in your project root directory, and `index.php` at the same level, then you can use `$config['composer_autoload'] = realpath (APPPATH.'../vendor/ autoload.php');` the way to introduce Composer

Comment: Is that to say,I must use composer to load the thrift? The project do't use composer, is there other ways?

Comment: Ci is not supported by namespace. If you don't want to use composer and want to use Ci, then don't use namespace. If you want to use namespaces, I suggest you use laravel

Comment: I see,CI is not supported by namespace.I  think that, is all supported by namespace ,when php's version is above 5.3.

Comment: yes,when php's version is above 5.3.  is all supported by namespace.but php how to know find those namespace,if you not include those file?

Comment: In the code,I try to use the thrift `ThriftClassLoader` to load the `MyServiceClient` for me.But it does't work.

Comment: if you want to use the thrift ThriftClassLoader to load the MyServiceClient         You should use the CI method to load ThriftClassLoader, otherwise, CI doesn't know the way